# Sunspot Solr fulltext search-time score boost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I am using  Solr search-engine in our Ruby On Rails app.
using the sunspot gem for the implementation.

I have a couple of questions regarding the fulltext boosting mechanisem.
Im trying to boost certain results up the result set if they meet certain condition,
So lets say:

```
# Posts with pizza, scored higher if featured
Post.search do
  fulltext 'pizza' do
     boost(2.0) { with(:featured, true) }
  end
end
```

i would expect all the Posts that contain 'pizza' and are featured = true,
will get a score of **2.0** and all the rest to not get scored at all OR get a score of **0**.

What actually happens is that all Posts with featured=true, get a score number which i cant predict (ie. **5.089861**)
regardless of the **2.0** i set in the search block.

Even if i increase the boosting number to **20.0** or **50.0**, or if i add another boost if the Post matched another condition, the actual scores are still in the **5.XXX** zone...

Moreover, Posts that are are featured=false, also have a score, of **0.09928045**(ish)
which i would expect to be an absolute **0**.

Can anyone further explain how the scoring mechanism work, specifically:

1. How can i control the actual score value (since 2.0 doesnt really give a score value of 2)
2. Why objects that don't meet the scoring condition, still gets a score (though lower)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Scoring doesn't work that way. Sunspot is literally boosting the score, it is not setting the score to the exact value. This is also why non-boosted fields returns a lower value.

[This page](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_0_3/scoring.html) describe how scoring (and boosting) works on the Lucene level.

Since this is not the way Sunspot / Solr / Lucene is intended to work, I doubt that there is a setting to allow you to fix the score, actually I can't think of a use case where you'd need to do this.

But if you really want to it should be fairly easy to implement your own solution :

- For returning only values which satisfy a certain field condition, you should use [sunspot-solr faceting](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot#faceting).
- Then you can patch the result to give it whatever score you want.